# Sloping ditch for corrugated pipe

Tags: gutters

I would like to bridge a 80 foot corrugated pipe into an existing section.

[image]

While digging the ditch to for the 80 foot section.  Is there any ditch \ trench techniques or tools to ensure that at any point the slope is either flat or downwards?

## Update

For context, a bird's eye view is provided of the building.  The above photo is snapped from the southeast corner of the building.  Building is approximately 80' by 80'

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For an even slope.

set-up profiles (frames, or stakes) at each end and run a sloping string line between them. Measure down to the floor of the ditch from the string line with a stick of appropriate length.  You could possibly tie one and of the string to the downpipe. and the other to a stake

If you don't need an even slope just use a spirit level (repeatedly) to confirm that the floor of the trench is still sloping as you are digging it.

Comment: I have done similar a string pulled tight is fairly easy or go high tech with a laser..

Comment: @Jasen and EdBeal. Excellent ideas.  Any references (especially videos) are appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Pound a stick into the ground and tie a string to it. Do the same at the other end. Check slope with a level.  No video needed.

Answer (score 2):

An 8 or 10 foot board, with a 4 foot level attached, the "downhill" end of the level supported by a 1 inch block = 1/4 inch per foot level reference. Usually a bit better for use in a trench than just a 4 foot level with a block taped to it.

The string+stick method also works. Mark level on both ends, then drop the downhill end 20 inches for a 1/4 inch per foot reference over the whole trench. Put a line on the stick and check whether this line is above or below the string indicating a need to dig or fill. The "stick" can be a tool handle you are already using to move dirt.

Use a 1/2" block or drop the string 10 inches if you want 1/8 inch per foot. It is generally considered dubious to go much beyond 1/4" per foot (without going near vertical) as it tends to allow solids (roof debris in this case) to build up in the pipe, as opposed to being carried by the water flow. I have seen multiple "steeply sloped so it will drain good" pipes plugged solid.